# How can I use fetchplan with Java API?

Tags: java, orientdb

As stated [here](http://www.orientechnologies.com/docs/last/orientdb.wiki/Fetching-Strategies.html#format), if I define `[*]in_*:-2 out_*:-2` as fetchplan, the query should return only properties and none info about the edges.

```
    OrientGraph graph = new OrientGraph(URL, USER, USER);
    try {
        Iterable resultList = graph.command(new OSQLSynchQuery("select from #11:0")).setFetchPlan("[*]in_*:-2 out_*:-2").execute();
        OrientVertex user = (OrientVertex) resultList.iterator().next();
        for (String s : user.getRecord().fieldNames()) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

        Iterable resultList2 = graph.command(new OSQLSynchQuery("select from #11:0")).execute();
        OrientVertex user2 = (OrientVertex) resultList2.iterator().next();
        for (String s : user2.getRecord().fieldNames()) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    } finally {
        graph.shutdown();
    }
```

I'm having the same output (that includes info about edges), with and without fetchplan. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With network protocol, Fetch plan is to optimize network transfer, not to exclude connections. In the case above OrientDB client will fetch the connected edges if excluded by fetch plan.

Comment: Hi @Lvca. Is there a way I can see what is being fetched by the query without fetching the connected edges?

Comment: Only if you enable the tracing of binary protocol: `-Dnetwork.binary.debug=true`